# Loop a CSS3 animation

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I'm trying to loop a css3 animation between 3 elements, after the 3rd element ends, I want to restart the animation and so on...

Here's my code:

```css
    .oferta-prods.run-animation img{
        animation-name:fadeIn;
        animation-duration:4s;
        animation-timing-function:ease-in-out;
        opacity:0;
    }
    .oferta-prods.run-animation img:nth-child(1){animation-delay:0s;}
    .oferta-prods.run-animation img:nth-child(2){animation-delay:4s;}
    .oferta-prods.run-animation img:nth-child(3){animation-delay:8s;}
    @keyframes fadeIn{
        0%{
            opacity:0;
        }
        10%{
            opacity:1;
        }
        90%{
            opacity:1;
        }
        100%{
            opacity:0;
        }
    }
```

```html
<div class="oferta-prods run-animation">
         <img src="assets/House.svg">
         <img src="assets/Car.svg">
         <img src="assets/Beach.svg">
    </div>
```

So, the idea is, element 1 starts animation then ends, element 2 starts animation then ends, then element 3 starts animation then ends. After this, I want to automatically begin a new cycle after the 3 elements end the animation.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by defining 3 diferent animations with different execution timers. 
Following my coding example bellow, we divide 100% / 3, and that gives us around 33%, meaning, that every image should run the animation for 33% of the animation total time.

Take a look at this example:

```css
ody {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100vh;
}

.animation-wrapper div {
  width: 20px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.animation-wrapper .anim-1 {
  background-color: red;
  animation: animation1 4s infinite ease-in-out;
}

.animation-wrapper .anim-2 {
  background-color: blue;
  animation: animation2 4s infinite ease-in-out;
}

.animation-wrapper .anim-3 {
  background-color: green;
  animation: animation3 4s infinite ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes animation1{
    0%{
        transform: translateX(0);
    }   
    
    16.5%{
        transform: translateX(20px);
    }

    33%{
        transform: translateX(0);
    }

    100%{
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}


@keyframes animation2{
    0%{
        transform: translateX(0);
    }

    33%{
        transform: translateX(0);
    }

    49.5%{
        transform: translateX(20px);
    }

    66%{
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    
    100%{
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}

@keyframes animation3{
    0%{
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
   
    66%{
        transform: translateX(0);
    }

    82.5%{
        transform: translateX(20px);
    }

    99%{
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    
    100%{
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}
```

```html
    <div class="animation-wrapper">
        <div class="anim-1"></div>
        <div class="anim-2"></div>
        <div class="anim-3"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!!

Comment: No problem, don't forget to mark this answer as "correct" if you think that's the case :)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use Javascript to [restart the animation](https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-restart-a-css-animation-with-javascript-and-what-is-the-dom-reflow-a86e8b6df00f). It involves triggering a DOM reflow, so it may not be the best way on a heavy page.

```js
const lastImage = document.querySelector(".oferta-prods.run-animation img:nth-child(3)");
lastImage.addEventListener("animationend", () => {
  lastImage.parentNode.classList.remove("run-animation");
  void lastImage.offsetWidth; // trigger DOM reflow
  lastImage.parentNode.classList.add("run-animation");
});
```

```css
.oferta-prods.run-animation img {
  animation: 4s ease-in-out fadeIn;
  opacity: 0;
}

.oferta-prods.run-animation img:nth-child(1) { animation-delay: 0s; }
.oferta-prods.run-animation img:nth-child(2) { animation-delay: 4s; }
.oferta-prods.run-animation img:nth-child(3) { animation-delay: 8s; }

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% { opacity: 0; }
  10% { opacity: 1; }
  90% { opacity: 1; }
  100% {opacity: 0; }
}
```

```html
<div class="oferta-prods run-animation">
  <img src="assets/House.svg">
  <img src="assets/Car.svg">
  <img src="assets/Beach.svg">
</div>
```